# Read-only file system error for mounted media

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, permissions, mount, windows-10

On my workstation I've Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 18.04 on an SSD and one HD for other process.
Now I need to create the virtual environment for python3 on a folder inside the HDD but when I try to do this via terminal I see this:

> Error: [Errno 30] Read-only file system:
>   '/media/user/DOC_HD1/DEV_FOLDER/devenv'

How I can solve this? 
I'm not an expert of Linux systems and I'm trying to pass from Windows.

NB: DOC_HD1 contain 1TB of fundamentals documents and I hope that the solution don't delete anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The volume is mounted read only, as it appears. It is not possible to know the details from a distance, but likely, your HD is formatted in the ntfs file system, the file system of MS Windows. That file system may be inconsistent at this time. In such case, Ubuntu won't mount it, or perhaps may mount it read-only.

Close down Ubuntu, start up Windows. Using the disk utilities of Windows, check and repair the file system on the disk concerned.

Then shut down Windows *fully*, i.e., no hibernate. This is to make sure that Windows fully closes the disk. If after this, the file system is consistent, Ubuntu will mount the drive with read and write permissions.

Comment: Yes, now I see that my HD is NTFS. If I format it in the FAT32 do you think that I can solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, but I think I gave you another solution. If you reformat, then make it ext4.

Comment: I've solved with formatting of the HDD in NTFS from Windows 10

Comment: Feel free to reformat your drive every time you have the issue. It will, however, be much more convenient to check the file system now and then in Windows. To keep the drive healthy, always unmount it properly, be it  in linux or windows.

Comment: Also see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249111/media-data-is-read-only-file-system-now-worked-fine-before

Answer (score 1):

In short, the problem comes from Windows, so keep in mind each time you want to shut down your Windows you should use the CMD and run the following command:

```
shutdown /s
```

After that, Windows will shut down immediately & you can now start up Ubuntu.

Comment: after running a lot of mount queries finally got this one. worked as a charm. thanks man