# /media/data is Read-only file system now, worked fine before

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, mount, fstab

Today I opened my laptop and noticed that I can't write anything to `/media/data` which is my `/dev/nvme0n1p6` partition. I have tried

```
sudo chown username:root /media/data
sudo chmod 700 /media/data
```

Both resulted in

```
changing permissions of '/media/data': Read-only file system
```

My `/etc/fstab` file is configured as follows:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=33fb895b-1070-4b0d-b46f-16faea98e719 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=E01B-2131  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=70D3E01334D0FA8A  /media/data       ntfs    defaults      0       2
```

while `sudo blkid` output is:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="Odzyskiwanie" UUID="0CEA1923EA190A9A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="f1348084-e57c-44e1-947f-398979b8d4d3"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="E01B-2131" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="3916c15a-c6c6-47ca-9b94-2ade6f932000"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: UUID="4FAB6EAE728682F0" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="217770cc-5238-438f-b1fc-93c9f37f4824"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: UUID="33fb895b-1070-4b0d-b46f-16faea98e719" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="77762ece-89b6-4092-ad22-e9b5ba1167ba"
/dev/nvme0n1p6: UUID="70D3E01334D0FA8A" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="dos" PARTLABEL="data" PARTUUID="202ad57b-2bdb-48eb-949e-a3a2d9d403b9"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop16: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1: PTUUID="4cbb7e4c-247b-4621-9aa9-66f332ee2907" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="09e7215b-b10c-45d6-b28d-f45a5281d5f5"
```

What might have caused this unexpected change (mounting as above in `/etc/fstab` file worked fine before) and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `fsck` on the partition in question?

Comment: I just did `sudo unmount /dev/nvme0n1p6` and `sudo fsck -p /dev/nvme0n1p6`, but nothing seemed to happened - the return message was `fsck from util-linux 2.31.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me was to boot Ubuntu from USB and do:

```bsh
sudo ntfsfix /dev/nvme0n1p6
```